# Problem with redirecting and links using MVC in PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I try to go into MVC but come to a problem that is not explained anywhere, it is how to redirect from one to another controller.

I'm using the following .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteCond% {REQUEST_FILENAME}!-F 
RewriteCond% {REQUEST_FILENAME}!-D 

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php? Url = $ 1 [L, QSA]
```

to use the controller directly after it put its methods and id th.

All this work accessing them in a standard way but when choosing a view to further pages ienata used directly as the controller.

```
<a href="next_page_controler"> NEXT_PAGE </ a>
```

and access the next controller, but when I want to access methods must use

```
<a href="next_page_controler/**controler_model**"> NEXT-pAGE_MODEL </ a>
```

and here we have two problems :

1. IN repeatedly link in address bar is displayed once again repeated as

   `www.site_pat/next_page_controler/next_page_controler/next_page_controler/next_page_controler/next_page_controler/controler_model`
2. When you try to redirect as the method controler_model using header (`Location: controler_name`); nothing gets pulls no message or anything just want to try but the redirect does not work .

How to solve the problems I guess a lot of you have encountered these are basic things and I think that shouting at all began to work with framework should understand these basics.

Answer (score 1):

Theres something wrong with your htaccess, should be something like...

```
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}!-F 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}!-D 

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L, QSA]
```

Comment: @prodigitalson coud you give me an example

Comment: I made a bootstrap file to get the url from index.php?url=
and it's work but i ges the problem is not in .htpaccess i nead an example with links and redirection.

Answer (score 1):

*UPDATE*:

> @prodigitalson coud you give me an example

So a super simple example might look like the following code. Ive never actually written a router from sractch because im typically using a framework, so there are probably soem features youll need that this doesnt include... Routing is a fairly complex things depending on how resuable you want it to be. I would reommend looking at how a few different php frameworks do it for good examples.

```
// define routes as a regular expression to match
$routes = array(
  'default' => array(
     'url' => '#^/categories/(?P<category_slug>\w*(/.*)?$#',
     'controller' => 'CategoryController'
   )
  )
);

// request - you should probably encapsulate this in a model 
$request = array();

// loop through routes and see if we have a match
foreach($routes as $route){
  // on the first match we assign variables to the request and then
  // stop processing the routes
  if(preg_match($route['url'], $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $params)){
    $request['controller'] = $route['controller'];
    $request['params'] = $params;
    $request['uri'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    break;
  }
}

// check that we found a match
if(!empty($request)){
  // dispatch the request to the proper controller
  $controllerClass = $request['controller'];
  $controller = new $controllerClass();

  // because we used named subpatterns int he regex above we can access parameters
  // inside the CategoryController::execute() with $request['params']['category_slug']
  $response = $controller->execute($request);
} else {
  // send 404
}

// in this example $controller->execute() returns the compiled HTML to render, but
// but in most systems ive used it returns a View object, or the name of the template to
// to be rendered - whatever happens here this is where you send your response

print $response;
exit(0);
```

---

You shouldnt be implementing your controller routing soley from .htaccess. You should simple have all request other than for static assets go to index.php. Then on the php side you firgure out where to dispatch the request based on the pattern of the url.